# Downloading calendar data in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

I am trying to download google calendar data.

I am following a tutorial [this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-google-calendars--mobile-19155) according to which implementing some of the GoogleOAuth delegate methods will let me get my desired data.

First I converted the response JSON data into an NSDictionary object and after that, I, NSLog this dictionary, to see the way the returned data is formed which is as shown below.

```
calendarInfoDict is {
    etag = "\"1436255371893000\"";
    items =     (
                {
            accessRole = owner;
            backgroundColor = "#9a9cff";
            colorId = 17;
            defaultReminders =             (
                                {
                    method = popup;
                    minutes = 30;
                }
            );
            etag = "\"1436255371893000\"";
            foregroundColor = "#000000";
            id = "sabiranthapa@gmail.com";
            kind = "calendar#calendarListEntry";
            notificationSettings =             {
                notifications =                 (
                                        {
                        method = email;
                        type = eventCreation;
                    },
                                        {
                        method = email;
                        type = eventChange;
                    },
                                        {
                        method = email;
                        type = eventCancellation;
                    },
                                        {
                        method = email;
                        type = eventResponse;
                    }
                );
            };
            primary = 1;
            selected = 1;
            summary = "sabiranthapa@gmail.com";
            timeZone = "Asia/Calcutta";
        },
                {
            accessRole = reader;
            backgroundColor = "#92e1c0";
            colorId = 13;
            defaultReminders =             (
            );
            description = "Displays birthdays of people in Google Contacts and optionally \"Your Circles\" from Google+. Also displays anniversary and other event dates from Google Contacts, if applicable.";
            etag = "\"1436255358367000\"";
            foregroundColor = "#000000";
            id = "#contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com";
            kind = "calendar#calendarListEntry";
            summary = Birthdays;
            timeZone = "Asia/Calcutta";
        }
    );
    kind = "calendar#calendarList";
    nextSyncToken = 00001436255371893000;
}
```

According to tutorial there is a block containing a bunch of information regarding every calendar I have created in Google Calendars inside curly bracket. But I am not getting any events that I have saved which can be seen in Google Calendar after signing in gmail but not in my apps where I need to work with it.

My code is

```
-(void)responseFromServiceWasReceived:(NSString *)responseJSONAsString andResponseJSONAsData:(NSData *)responseJSONAsData{

    NSError *error;

    if ([responseJSONAsString rangeOfString:@"calendarList"].location != NSNotFound) {

        NSDictionary *calendarInfoDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseJSONAsData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

       NSLog(@"calendarInfoDict is %@", calendarInfoDict);

        if (error) {           
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        else{            
            NSArray *calendarsInfo = [calendarInfoDict objectForKey:@"items"];

            if (_arrGoogleCalendars == nil) {
                _arrGoogleCalendars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            }           

            for (int i=0; i<[calendarsInfo count]; i++) {

                NSDictionary *currentCalDict = [calendarsInfo objectAtIndex:i];               


                NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[currentCalDict objectForKey:@"id"],
                                   [currentCalDict objectForKey:@"summary"],
                                   nil];                             NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"id", @"summary", nil];

                [_arrGoogleCalendars addObject:
                 [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values forKeys:keys]];
            }

            _dictCurrentCalendar = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[_arrGoogleCalendars objectAtIndex:0]];


            [_barItemPost setEnabled:YES];
            [_barItemRevokeAccess setEnabled:YES];


            [self showOrHideActivityIndicatorView];
```

But I always end up with condition

```
if (_arrGoogleCalendars == nil) {
        _arrGoogleCalendars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
```

without able to access my events.
How can I download (or access) my Events from google calendar?